# How can i put my project in Threejs.og?

Tags: project, demo

Please help me with this. I designed a website by ThreeJs. how can i put it in first page of Threejs.org in projects page?

Comment: Please take a look at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

MrDoob has answered this on github, [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5454) and [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/4821).

> Projects can't be submitted to be featured. The way it tends to work is by me looking on twitter for the hashtag #threejs from time to time and if I find a project that impresses me I feature it :)